# Jquery on change each only updates one input

Tags: jquery, each, onchange

I am trying to understand how it works and why it only updates the input I am working on.

I have the following 3 inputs:

```
  <div class="row member">
          <div class="input-field col s4 nogap">
            <input id="money" type="text" value="0">
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s4 nogap">
            <input id="hours" type="number" step="any" class="validate" value="0">
          </div>
          <div class="input-field col s4 nogap">
            <input id="name" type="text" class="validate">
          </div>
        </div>
```

and the following js:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
var totalHours = 0;
var totalwHours = 0;
var money = 0;
var perHours = 0;

var wHours = [0, 0 , 0 ,0 , 0 ,0];
var wMoney = [0, 0 , 0 ,0 , 0 ,0];


$('div.member').each(function(index, obj){
  $(this).change(function(){
    myH = $(this).find('#hours').val();
    wHours[index] = myH;
    var totalHours = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < wHours.length; i++) {
      totalHours += wHours[i] << 0;
    }
    perHours = money / totalHours;
    wMoney[index] = perHours * myH;
    $(this).find('#money').val(wMoney[index]);
  });
});
});
```

It all works great, the variables are updating correctly but for example if I am working on member 2 and change his hours, only his "money" input is updating and the other two stay the same until I am changing their "hours" field.

I really want to uderstand how to work with `.change` and `.each` together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is because you can only edit one text field at the same time. So, only one `onChange` event is fired logically. Also, you don´t need the each loop, because you can directly operate on the returned jQuery array with `.change`. So, using your example this should do the trick for you:

```
$('div.member').each(function(index, obj){
  $(this).change(function(){
    $('div.member').each(function (ind, textfields) {
        myH = $(this).find('#hours').val();
        wHours[index] = myH;
        var totalHours = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < wHours.length; i++) {
          totalHours += wHours[i] << 0;
        }
        perHours = money / totalHours;
        wMoney[index] = perHours * myH;
        $(this).find('#money').val(wMoney[index]);
    });
  });
});
```

Also, giving an id to the money input field does not make sense, because the html `id` attribute value should b e unique in the whole html document. Use `name` instead, it can occure more than once. So, change the line `myH = $(this).find('#hours').val();` to `myH = $(this).find('input[name="hours"]').first().val();`. `.first()` is used to get the first element of the array if it is one.

So, the full solution in a shorter way looks like that:

```
$('div.member').change(function (sender) {
    sender.preventDefault();
    $('div.member').each(function (ind, textfields) {
        myH = $(this).find('input[name="hours"]').first().val();
        wHours[index] = myH;
        var totalHours = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < wHours.length; i++) {
          totalHours += wHours[i] << 0;
        }
        perHours = money / totalHours;
        wMoney[index] = perHours * myH;
        $(this).find('#money').val(wMoney[index]);
    });
});
```

You may also need the `sender.preventDefault()` line to prevent the browser from executing the default action. If you have trouble, keep this in mind.